# Matching current Location with Database list of location with in 50 miles

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, location, android-geofence

i am trying to  work on application , in which i have List of location from database and i want to check Which location from database is near to my current location within few miles like 20 miles and list got refreshed automatically with the refined Location and then send notification to user that you have enter to this location...

I have searched over this and come to know about Geofencing But i did not get it properly.. so please suggest me how should i start working on it ... Any sample , code or link will be helpful

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used one function `distanceTo` to calculate distance between to `Locations`.

I have coded it for only 100 mtr, you need to change value of distance you want to compare with.

```
private boolean isMarkerIn100(ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        Location locationA = new Location("LocationA");
        locationA.setLatitude(latitude);
        locationA.setLongitude(longitude);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            Location locationB = new Location("LocationB");
            locationB.setLatitude(arrayList.get(i).getLat());
            locationB.setLongitude(arrayList.get(i).getLng());
            if (locationA.distanceTo(locationB) < 100 && arrayList.get(i).getHit() > 4) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In above code, `latitude` and `longitude` are for my (User's) location (Say locationA) and `ArrayList` is data from database with `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: thanks ... but how i can retrieve data from sqlite like you did in arraylist...
i have made two different list like this 

ArrayList<String> al_getLatitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al_get_longitude = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: i think i have to make Arraylist in batabase class also ... but dont know .. can you post that code also

Comment: For me ArrayList data is coming from server, So you need to write code for your local data base. Also make a Model class for Lat and lng